# Does Scala have floatToIntBits and intBitsToFloat methods?

Tags: java, scala, floating-point, bit-manipulation

`floatToIntBits` and `intBitsToFloat` are methods in Java's Float class. Does Scala have those functionalities?

Comment: You know that you can import Java classes/methods into Scala?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes. I do. I can import everything Java into Scala: Yet we have two languages.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you're asking.  `Float` is a class in a library (package); you're free to import that class/package.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I am clearly asking about equivalent `functionalities`. Here is an example: Java has `Integer.parseInt` and Scala simply uses `toInt` to do the same thing. You can downvote to your heart's content. It's not my fault if you misread a simple question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, and there's no need for the attitude (which ironically makes me now want to downvote).

Comment: I don't see why the question deserves a down vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Scala is a JVM language, you can access any and all features of whichever Java runtime you're using.  This is a trait of all languages that run on top of the JVM, which is why it's so popular (JRuby, Clojure, etc.)

You might have to explicitly state that you want to access the Java Float type's static method, since Scala also has a Float class, but other than that you should be fine.

```
java.lang.Float.floatToIntBits()
```

In other words, there is no reason for Scala to implement this since Java already does it.  If you need the feature as it already exists in Java, just use the Java implementation.

Regarding your clarifying comments:

`Integer.parseInt` is a static method on the `Integer` class with a `String` as its input, whereas Scala's `toInt` is a commonly implemented instance method on instances of many different classes outside of Strings for extracting integer representations.  They "do" the same thing in only a very loose sense; using a `String` as an input to `Integer.ParseInt` or calling `toInt` on a `String` will achieve the same result, but they *aren't* the same thing, so it's not a very apt comparison.  Design-wise and looking at the language as a whole, they expose two very different interfaces.  There is some overlap, as we can see in the String-specific case, but in the general case the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) philosophy is very much in play here where there would be absolutely no need for Scala to re-implement something specific like `floatToIntBits`

Comment: The comparison to `Integer.parseInt` was to shed light on what is meant by `functionality`; it wasn't meant to express an `onto` relationship. Your `DRY` explanation is good, but that discredits why Scala redefines `List` instead of using Java's LinkedList or Java's List interface (you will find other examples). All the same, your answer means that "No, Scala does not redefine that functionality". And since I searched and could not find any, and you seem to know Scala, you must be correct.

Comment: @learner Scala re-implements Lists because the underlying structures/iterators are different so that they can be more readily used in a functional manner.

Answer (score 1):

Scala can use them from Java.

```
scala> java.lang.Float.floatToIntBits(1.0f)
res0: Int = 1065353216

scala> java.lang.Float.intBitsToFloat(1)
res1: Float = 1.4E-45
```